# Relation between multiplicity and star cyclicity of a Normal operator on a separable Hilbert Space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $N$ be a normal operator acting on a separable Hilbert Space. If $N$ is a star cyclic then it is unitarily equivalent to the multiplication operator $M_z$ by coordinate function on the $L^2(\mu)$ for some positive measure $\mu$ supported on the spectrum of $N.$ This suggest that the multiplicity function for $N$ is equal to $1$ almost everywhere.

My question is whether the following statement is true or not. 
If $N$ is a $n$ star cyclic then it has uniform multiplicty $n$ almost everywhere and vice versa that is if $N$ has uniform multiplicty $n$ almost everywhere then $N$ is $n$ star cyclic.